# For complex function : $f'(z)$ exists $\implies$ $f$ continous in $z$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, derivatives, complex-numbers, continuity

Consider a complex function $f(z): A\subset\mathbb C \to\mathbb C$.

If the derivative of $f$ exists then $f$ must necessarily be a continuous function?

Is the following true?   $f'(z)$ exists $\implies$ $f$ continuous in $z$

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Comment: To go a step further, not only is it continuous, it is analytic.

Comment: You can prove it directly from the definition of a derivative. Just consider $\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}\cdot h$ . You do it just like for the functions of real variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick proof: Let $f:A\to\mathbb C$ and let $z_0\in A$ be an accumulation point of $A$. Suppose $f'(z_0)$ exists, i.e. the limit

$$\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}=L$$

exists and $L\in\mathbb C$. Then we have

$$\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)-f(z_0)=\lim_{z\to z_0}(f(z)-f(z_0))=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}(z-z_0)=f'(z_0)\cdot 0=0$$

Thus, $\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)=f(z_0)$ and $f$ is continuous in $z_0$.

Comment: Albeit subtle, the assumption should be that the limit exists and is finite.  Also, you repeated $\lim_{z\to z_0}(f(z)-f(z_0))$ twice although there were missing outer parentheses in the first occurrence (perhaps this is something you intended).  Lastly, the proof relies on the theorem that the limit of a product of complex functions equals the product of the limits (when both limits exist and are finite) of the complex functions.

Comment: @MarkViola With "the limit exists" I mean that the limit is a member in the considered space, e.g. a real or complex number. Also, this is not a repetition, but the limit expression is meant to be read as any unary connective, i.e. for $\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)=L$, the expression $\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)-f(z_0)$ means $L-f(z_0)$. Lastly, I agree the proof relies on the properties of limits that the distribute over products and sums, if the corresponding inner limits exist.

Comment: Why would $A$ be open though. It would suffice if $z_0$ would be an accumulation point of $A$

Comment: @Jakobian Indeed it would, out of habit I just projected my usual setting on the answer. But I'll edit that in thanks for the remark.

Comment: I agree with the first point, but you might just consider making it explicit just to tighten things a bit.  As for the second point, I had commented parenthetically that you might have intended this step.

Comment: @MarkViola Oh, I'm very sorry that slipped past me. And I think you're right, I'll edit that in.

Comment: (+1) for the succinct and clear solution